# Gaussian fit unable to work

Tags: fitting

I hace a set of data, each of them contains 101 points. For example, one of them is:

```
{0.0090615, 0.00889849, 0.00853851, 0.00849735, 0.00848166, 0.00837616, 0.00812348, 0.0078692, 0.00766806, 0.00759519, 0.00765185, 0.00704647, 0.00690229, 0.00696524, 0.00680134, 0.00665558, 0.00642188, 0.00627526, 0.00617638, 0.00620749, 0.00572877, 0.00564207, 0.00550909, 0.00535156, 0.00515859, 0.00497775, 0.00466083, 0.00495397, 0.00439545, 0.00446824, 0.00433572, 0.00429334, 0.00397183, 0.0040075, 0.00374434, 0.00390397, 0.00356792, 0.00339951, 0.0036146, 0.00348768, 0.00341356, 0.00337594, 0.00359416, 0.00343362, 0.0035095, 0.00359521, 0.00342122, 0.00352321, 0.00381156, 0.00359446, 0.00373883, 0.00384949, 0.00384067, 0.0039852, 0.00398274, 0.00394904, 0.00387428, 0.00397236, 0.00385905, 0.00365906, 0.00354681, 0.00345719, 0.00352252, 0.00344869, 0.0034675, 0.00346053, 0.00353718, 0.00381765, 0.00392134, 0.00414701, 0.00426225, 0.00439211, 0.00473225, 0.0048565, 0.0050446, 0.00503591, 0.0052194, 0.00511466, 0.00487832, 0.00484313, 0.00461116, 0.00438661, 0.00423772, 0.00399403, 0.00374405, 0.00355533, 0.00337457, 0.00325582, 0.00311438, 0.00296106, 0.00273681, 0.00267255, 0.00277066, 0.00267897, 0.00249685, 0.00242084, 0.00237808, 0.00238189, 0.00227136, 0.0022889, 0.00229346}
```

This list of points has 2 peaks (and a polynomial noise near zero), I need to use gaussian fit to find all the 2 peaks. I tried FindFit and NonLinearModelFit function, and let them fit a model of a summation of 2 or 3 gaussian functions. But the result is bad, the small peak will always be ignored unless I input the peak location and amplitude of the small peak as initial condition. But I have thousands of similar data need to fit, so I cannot input the initial condition one by one, I need something that can autimatically find all the peaks.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you seen [`FindPeaks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPeaks.html) ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). Please [edit] your question and tell us what you have tried, and why it didn't work in detail, show due diligence, and include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.